# What is the best way to communicate with MongoDB from node.js server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I used mongoose but someone said it is outdated way to communicate with db.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked that someone what the correct way is then.

Comment: there isn't a best way to communicate with a mongo database, everything depend on you, you must choose package that make you job easy, and that work perfectectly and that are not outdated

Comment: Thanks, everyone, I couldn't able to ask that guy who reviewed my code because i got feedback from another person, I did try to look for what could be the better way to do that job but i found the most preferred way is by mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a sample of code with the MongoDB official driver:

https://github.com/davicente/SGBootcampNode